# Taking a snapshot of a SurfaceView

Tags: android, screenshot, surfaceview, snapshot

How do I take a snapshot of a SurfaceView? I've done some research but I can't find a solution. Taking a snap shot with a View is working fine, but with SurfaceView it gives a black screen image.

```
View v1 = surfaceview.getRootView();
```

(or)

```
View v1 = linearlayout.getRootView(); //linearlayout which holds surfaceview like linear.addView(surfaceViewObj);
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmp = v1.getDrawingCache();
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/myzoomSnap.jpg";

try {
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
    bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
}
```

Some people have mentioned that SurfaceView is not present over a window unlike other views. So is it even possible to take snapshot of a SurfaceView?